# Are there point-free formulations of algebraic theories?

Tags: logic, category-theory

In logic, a first-order type theory can usually be presented in a [tacit/point-free style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming); each deductive rule can be phrased as a diagram ([WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram_(category_theory)), [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/diagram)) and interpreted in a carefully-chosen category whose objects are (collections of) first-order elements.

**To what extent can we do this for algebraic theories in general? Is this only possible for particular theories, like equational or Lawvere theories?**

I think that it can be done for Lawvere theories ([WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawvere_theory), [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory)) but I'd appreciate learning that other folks have already laid down some nomenclature and structure.

For a simple example, consider the theory of magmas ([WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)), [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/magma)). A traditional presentation of this theory has a single operation, $m : M \times M \to M$, and composite operations like $(x, y, z, w) \mapsto m(m(x, y), m(z, w))$. If we imagine a tacit presentation, then we may end up with syntax like this:

```
m rot rot m m
```

Using [Forth-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)) stack mechanics and the operation $rot : \dots M_0 \times M_1 \times M_2 \to \dots M_2 \times M_0 \times M_1$ which permutes the stack. Or perhaps we have syntax like this:

```
(comp (pair m m) m)
```

Using [ML-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)) calling conventions and the operations $comp : Y^X \times Z^Y \to Z^X$ and $pair : Y^X \times W^Z \to (Y \times W)^{X \times Z}$.

Indices have been omitted for simplicity, but index selection is permitted with operations like $m_{0,2} : M \times X \times M \to M$ which select the 0th and 2nd components of a triple. Both Forth-style and ML-style tacit programmers have techniques for managing these indices.

Comment: I genuinely am not sure which site is best equipped to host this question. Feel free to migrate it to either PLDI (langdev.se) or Theoretical CS (cstheory.se) if it would fit better there. My secret hope is that some category theorist already did this in the 1990s and that an answer cites existing work, but I would understand if nobody's done it yet.

Comment: a category of objects for an algebraic theory is a category monadic over Set by a finitary monad, or something like that (I don't remember exactly but there's something in Riehl's category theory in context). That seems point free

Comment: related, https://mathoverflow.net/a/389158/7952 because most of these approaches seem "point-free" to me